# GeoServer Keeps Stopping Service

Tags: geoserver, linux

GeoServer version : 2.20.3

I have followed the following instructions to install GeoServer on a linux server on Digital ocean

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-i-install-or-use-geoserver-on-digital-ocean

Everything works until I close the SSH/Putty connection.

Only way to start again is to open SSH again and

```
cd /usr/share/geoserver/bin
sh startup.sh
```

Is there a way I can keep the GeoServer service running even after closing my SSH connection?

Answer (score 8):

You are running GeoServer as a foreground process, so when you log out it is terminated. A quick and dirty way to avoid this is to use `nohup` (no hang up) like this:

```
nohup sh startup.sh &
```

But you really need to run GeoServer as a service so that it is always running. So, rather than the platform independent binary (designed for testing) you want to follow the [Web archive instructions](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/war.html#installation-war) and add it to your [tomcat service](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: Thank so much for the help. Really apperciate it. Will try this out. Thanks